# testing with Rails Rspec - expected and got aren't matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Im quite new to Rspec with Rails. Im just trying to run some tests to see if a new user has been saved and if a name, email and password has been entered but it is not working for some reason as no tests are passing.
I'm going by this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71eKcNxwxVY. Ive copied everything apart from i didn't use a scaffold. I made a user model myself. thanks

```html
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true
end
```

```html
rspec

User
  validation tests
    ensures name presence (FAILED - 1)
    ensures email presence (FAILED - 2)
    ensures password presence (FAILED - 3)
    should save (FAILED - 4)

Failures:

  1) User validation tests ensures name presence
     Failure/Error: expect(user).to eq()
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User validation tests ensures email presence
     Failure/Error: expect(user).to eq(false)
     
       expected: false
            got: #<User id: nil, name: "ben", email: nil, password: "123123", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
     
       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User validation tests ensures password presence
     Failure/Error: expect(user).to eq(false)
     
       expected: false
            got: #<User id: nil, name: "ben", email: "ben@ben.com", password: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
     
       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User validation tests should save
     Failure/Error: expect(user).to eq(true)
     
       expected: true
            got: #<User id: nil, name: "ben", email: "ben@ben.com", password: "123123", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
     
       (compared using ==)
     
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,8 @@
       -true
       +#<User:0x00007fa8efdbb628
       + id: nil,
       + name: "ben",
       + email: "ben@ben.com",
       + password: "123123",
       + created_at: nil,
       + updated_at: nil>
       
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02486 seconds (files took 1.43 seconds to load)
4 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5 # User validation tests ensures name presence
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:10 # User validation tests ensures email presence
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:15 # User validation tests ensures password presence
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:20 # User validation tests should save
```

```html
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  context 'validation tests' do
    it "ensures name presence" do
        user = User.new(email: "ben@ben.com", password: "123123")
        expect(user).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'ensures email presence' do
        user = User.new(name:"ben", password: "123123")
        expect(user).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'ensures password presence' do
        user = User.new(email: "ben@ben.com", name: "ben")
        expect(user).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'should save' do
        user = User.new(email: "ben@ben.com", name: "ben", password: "123123")
        expect(user).to eq(true)
      end
end
end
```

Comment: Your expectations are incorrect. Try the user.errors array - look it up on the rails api and incorporate inn your tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing your tests, you are comparing the entire user object. You should instead compare the attribute you are looking for. Try something like this:

```
it "ensures name presence" do
  user = User.new(email: "ben@ben.com", password: "123123")
  expect(user.name).to be_nil
end
```

As you can see, I've added `expect(user.name)` instead of just `expect(user)`. Also, just for your information, when you use **.new**, it doesn't actually save the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing validity of User object try using `valid?` method. If an user is not valid then `user.valid?` would return `false`. If it is valid then it would return `true`.

Here is an example

```
    it 'ensures email presence' do
      user = User.new(name:"ben", password: "123123")
      expect(user.valid?).to eq(false)
    end
```

for validation tests you can also use [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers).